# Why does the animation loop go on forever?

Tags: javascript, gsap

I'm trying to make endless image switching after the scroll reaches a block and stops when it exits. But the cycle goes on endlessly in the end

```
c

onst images = ['/img/Landing/section/chat.png', '/img/Landing/section/chat1.png', '/img/Landing/section/chat2.png'];
  const myImage = document.getElementById('section-img');
  const imageSwitchTimeline = gsap.timeline({
    repeat: -1,
    repeatDelay: 0.5
  });
  
  images.forEach((image, index) => {
    imageSwitchTimeline.to(myImage, { duration: 1, opacity: 1, onComplete: () => {
      myImage.src = images[index % images.length];
    }});
  });

  imageSwitchTimeline.to(myImage, { duration: 1, opacity: 1 });

  ScrollTrigger.create({
    trigger: '#section',
    start: 'top center',
    end: 'bottom center',
    onEnter: () => {
      imageSwitchTimeline.play();
    },
    onLeaveBack: () => {      
      imageSwitchTimeline.pause();
    },
  });
```

Comment: `/assets/img/images[0].png` is literally the string `/assets/img/images[0].png` ... nothing to do with your `const images`

Comment: thanks, I fixed it because I add it dynamically through VUE. Here the example is incorrect

Comment: so, what's the issue? you want `src:"/assets/img/chat1.png"` to not static?

Comment: I want to replace the src of images. In my example, I showed how I try to replace at least 1 image with a static path, but even this does not work.